# Disable manually running pipelines for "Developer" role in Gitlab

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

Beyond disabling CI/CD completely or updating job definitions via rules to not execute via "web",  is there a way to prevent the "Developer" role from being able to manually start a pipeline in any branch?

Ideally, I would like to hide the

[image: Run Pipeline Image]

button. It would still be fine (and preferable) for the Developer role to be able to view pipeline and job results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## protected branches

Depending on your branching model you could [protect all branches](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/permissions.html#running-pipelines-on-protected-branches) and don't give developers the rights to push or merge directly on those branches you don't want the developers to run pipelines on.

## Alternativ: Restricting via pipeline file and API

You could also write your Pipeline file so that it checks whether the pipeline [was run manually](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules) or not and only allow this for certain users. You can get the members of your project or group and their access levels (roles) [via the API](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/members.html)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is not possible to restrict roles or to create your own roles. There are a few issues/epics ([#1896](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/1896), [#12736](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/12736), [&4684](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4684)) on this topic, but implementation will take some time.
Unfortunately the epic has a [low priority](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/4684#note_537444287).